# Какие горячие клавиши лучше добавить в вебе?

Tags: hotkeys

Хочу к себе в веб-приложение добавить поддержку горячих клавиш: чтобы пользователь мог открывать пронумерованные ссылки на экране через клавиатуру.

Изначально хотел сделать это через ctrl + 0...9. Но потом оказалось, что это сочетание и так используется, например, в хроме для перехода по вкладкам. Потом пришел к варианту Ctrl + Shift + 0...9.

Есть ли какие-то стандарты/рекомендации/общедоступные размышления на тему добавления горячих клавиш на сайт? Может, есть какие-то устоявшиеся сочетания? Или где-то можно дополнительно прочитать об этом?